# Table with weird borders with the booktabs package

Tags: tables, booktabs

I'd like a table that looks like this in Beamer:

[image: nice table]

But the best I can do is this:

[image: ugly table]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|}\cmidrule{2-3}\noalign{\vskip-\belowrulesep}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & $M_2$ & $a$\\\hline
$M_1$ & $M_3$ &\\\noalign{\vskip-\aboverulesep}\cmidrule{1-2}
    \morecmidrules\cmidrule{1-2}\noalign{\vskip-\belowrulesep}
$b$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$x$}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Is the table I want possible?

Comment: Don't use booktabs with vertical lines

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I asked a related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683580/200958).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = { *{3}{c }},
        hline{1} = {1}{2-3}{},
        hline{2,4} = {1}{1-3}{},
        hline{3} = {1}{1-2}{rightpos = 0},
        hline{3} = {2}{1-2}{},
        vline{1} = {1}{2-3}{},
        vline{2} = {1}{1-3}{},
        vline{3} = {1}{1-2}{},
        vline{3} = {2}{1-2}{belowpos = 1},
        vline{4} = {1}{1-3}{belowpos = 1},
    }
     & $M_2$ & $a$ \\ 
    $M_1$ & $M_3$ & \\
    $b$ &  & $x$ \\
    \end{tblr}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to get a continuous gap also between the vertical lines on the right side, it might be better to use the `nicematrix` package, which combines the strengths of Ti*k*Z with the possibilities of tabulars (at least `tabularray` won't give you a nice result in this case):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ *{3}{c} }
     & $M_2$ & $a$ \\ 
    $M_1$ & $M_3$ & \\ 
    $b$ &  & $x$ \\
    \CodeAfter
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw 
                (1-|2) -- 
                ([xshift=-1pt]1-|3) -- 
                ([xshift=-1pt, yshift=1pt]3-|3) -- 
                ([yshift=1pt]3-|1) -- 
                (2-|1) -- (2-|2) -- cycle;
            \draw 
                ([xshift=1pt]1-|3) -- 
                (1-|4) -- (4-|4) -- (4-|1) --
                ([yshift=-1pt]3-|1) -- 
                ([xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt]3-|3) -- 
                cycle;
            \draw (2-|2) -- ([xshift=-1pt]2-|3)
                ([xshift=1pt]2-|3) -- (2-|4);
            \draw (2-|2) -- ([yshift=1pt]3-|2) 
                ([yshift=-1pt]3-|2) -- (4-|2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{NiceTabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this.  This is what I need.  I did not know about the `tabularray` package.

Comment: Your `nicematrix` answer is what I really want, I didn't ask for it in my post because I didn't think it was possible.

Comment: @user338955 You could also try to use a `NiceArray` since this uses math-mode, but you would need to change the syntax for the border drawings, I think.

Answer (score 6):

Tikz for you :-)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    , thick
    , n/.style = {
      , minimum width = 10mm
      , minimum height = 6mm
      , draw
    }
    , outer sep = 0
    , node distance = 0 and 0
  ]
    \node (M2) [n] {$M_2$};
    \node (M3) [below = of M2, n] {$M_3$};
    \node (M1) [left = of M3, n] {$M_1$};
    \node (a) [right = 1mm of M2, n] {$a$}; % add , minimum width = 7mm if you want narrower node
    \node (b) [below = 1mm of M1, n] {$b$};
    \node (x) [below = 7mm of a.south, minimum height = 6mm] {$x$};
    \draw (M2.north east) -- (a.north west);
    \draw (M2.south east) -- (a.south west);
    \draw (a.south west) |- (b.north east);
    \draw (a.south east) |- (b.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. This is very good, but I think the other answer using the `tabularray` package is what I am more interested in.

Comment: @user338955 I previously knew the power of `tabularray` but haven't used them frequently. Your question is also a great opportunity for me to catch up with the `tblr` trend :-)

Comment: Your solution is also nice. I was wondering whether an approach using the `nicematrix` package would also work ... in the end, you would also be able to draw with `tikz` between the cells

Answer (score 5):

With `hhline` package;

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|}
    \hhline{~|-|-|}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
        & $M_2$ & $a$   \\
    \hhline{-|--|}
$M_1$   & $M_3$ &       \\
    \hhline{:=:=:b|~|}
$b$     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
                &  $x$  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is the simplest one so far.

Comment: @user338955, many times some old, many times already seem to be  forgotten packages, make writing of table simply :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, in comparison to a some new packages like `tabularray`.  I should write "...some *good* old, ...",

Comment: I just asked a follow-up question based on this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683580/200958

Answer (score 3):

A  little patch to a simple `tabular` with the help of `array` to play with the intercolumn spaces (`@{}`):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}\sffamily\extrarowheight2pt
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|@{}p{2pt}@{}|l|}
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&M2&&a\\\hline
M1&M3&&\\\cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\vspace*{-12pt}}&%
\multicolumn{1}{@{\kern-.4pt\rule[8pt]{.4pt}{2.6pt}}c|}{}\\\cline{1-3}
b & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &  x \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```