# Horizontal tabular borders and `\arrayrulecolor` in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, booktabs, colortbl, hhline

When I tried implementing [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683548/200958) in a previous question, I discovered a problem involving horizontal tabular borders and `\arrayrulecolor`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs} %\cmidrule
\usepackage{hhline} %\hhline
\usepackage{colortbl} %\arrayrulecolor
\begin{document}
%\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\frame{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|}\hhline{~|-|-|}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & $M_2$ & $a$\\\hhline{-|--|}
$M_1$ & $M_3$ &\\\hhline{:=:=:b|~|}
$b$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $x$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|}\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & $M_2$ & $a$\\\hline
$M_1$ & $M_3$ &\\\hhline{:=:=:b|~|}
$b$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $x$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|}\cmidrule{2-3}\noalign{\vskip-\belowrulesep}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & $M_2$ & $a$\\\hline
$M_1$ & $M_3$ &\\\hhline{:=:=:b|~|}
$b$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $x$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

The code above (without `\arrayrulecolor`) has the output shown below.

[image: nice tables]

But including the `\arrayrulecolor` command (by removing the percent symbol in front of it), results in the output shown below.

[image: ugly tables]

That is, `\cline` and `\hhline` stop working when the `\arrayrulecolor` command is used (but `\cmidrule` still works).

Is there a way I can use `\cline` or `\hhline` and still get a different color for the borders?

Comment: Your MWE works fine in (any) other document class, but not with `beamer`. Since I'm not expert for `beamer` I don't know, what interaction between used packages cause this misbehaviour or is there a some bug in handling of colloes in `\hhline`s. What is strange, that `\hhline{:=:=:b|~|}` works as expected, but `\hhline{---}` vanish as you observed.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks for the observation.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404872/47927

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404903/47927) for a solution. The problem is that `beamer` redefines the macro `\reset@color` which is used to change the color for rules when using `hhline` together with `colortbl`. It is redefined, however, in a way so that things break.

MWE with fix:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{colortbl} %\arrayrulecolor
\usepackage{hhline} %\hhline
\makeatletter
\let\zz\reset@color
\def\reset@color{\kern\z@\zz}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}
\frame{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|}\hhline{~|-|-|}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & $M_2$ & $a$\\\hhline{-|--|}
$M_1$ & $M_3$ &\\\hhline{:=:=:b|~|}
$b$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $x$\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks, it works.

Comment: Huh,  you use solution proposed by @David Carlisle on my question from 2017! Apparently my memory is like a Swiss cheese, only  holes ... +1. Unfortunately this fix is still not integrated to `hhlines` (well David didn't promise this, but anyway ...